Flutter:IOS - This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleVersion [b1.0.0] in the Info.plist file must be a period-separated list
we are getting below error while uploading the flutter app build to apple store from xcode.
Can you please help us troubleshoot this issue?
This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleVersion [b1.0.0] in the Info.plist file must be a period-separated list of at most three non-negative integers. Please find more information about CFBundleVersion at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleversion (ID: dc3cc267-be9e-4bfa-922b-aed3d140f6e2)
Info.plist

pubsub.yaml:

Error from xcode:

Xcode error log



Goto ios/Runner/Info.plist

Find CFBundleVersion. It might be like
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>....</string>

Replace that from bellow tags.
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>


If above thing is correct. Then open ios folder in xcode.
In General tab  check version value in Identity section.
It should be empty.

Then run flutter clean and flutter pub get


this is how the inof.plist is present. but i have added info.plist in the main thread.

Can you share info.plist ?

Did you changed version from xcode ? check in runner/general/identity.

we tried to change it both in pubsub.yaml and in xcode directly. including harcoding the versions different major versions. but no luck :-(

Goto ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj then search MARKETING_VERSION. what are the values all of them ?

all the values have "1.0" MARKETING_VERSION = 1.0;

Then last option is delete ios folder then run flutter create . This will create ios folder again. But before doing this put your important this in separate folder.

deleted the ios and back using the flutter create command. still facing same issue? is it anything to do with the latest xcode and mac os? do we have any known issues?

I never faces this kind issue in my projects. If you can share your project on github. Then i will try on my mac at night.

I am sorry but unfortunately, it is company project. however, let me try to reproduce the error in a minified project and share. it might take some time(day or 2). but thanks a lot for your efforts.
